# css scroll snap points in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

is there a way to use CSS Scroll Sap Points in an ionic-content or ion-scroll? Something like this:

```
-webkit-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
-webkit-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100%);
```

I would like to have some vertical fullpage-scroll in a ion-slide-page (using horizontal ion-slides).

Any help is HIGHLY appreciated

Comment: is your problem only with snap points, or also to set vertical scroll with ion-slide? For the first point i recommend reading this: https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points/ (snap points is not fully supported and you will have to use a polyfill). For the second i can elaborate a quick answer if you have trouble.

Comment: thanks. the vertical scoll itsef in the ion-slide is not the problem. I am simply unable to figure out how I could apply the scroll-snap-points there. Since I am targeting mobile only, polyfill should not be necessary in my case. In the mean time I am using an ion-scroll with paging="true", but this kind of paging is not feeling really native:

`<ion-view view-title="Scoll">
<ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false" paging="true" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh">  
...myContent here
 </ion-scroll>
</ion-view>`

Answer (score 0):

Well worth revisiting this now in 2020 as scroll snap is widely supported. I created a reusable vertical scroll class like so:

```
.vertical-scroll {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.vertical-scroll > * {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And then just place that inside of your Ionic Content, with the children content of vertical-scroll being the items you want to scroll, for example:

```
  const loadNews = () => {
    return (
      <div className="vertical-scroll">
        {[...Array(n)].map((e, i) => (
          <LatestNewsCard
            date="24 hours ago"
            title="UFC 'Halifax' results and play-by-play!"
            className="full-height"
            key={i}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
```